# kendo ui grid, cannoet get sortable to work. getting error 'sortable': object is null or undefined

Tags: kendo-ui

I have downloaded the Telerik Kendo UI Web (GPL edition) control library.
i wrote a simple static page with an html table ,
included jquery 1.9.1, kendo.web.js scripts 
 (and the css files), then called:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
sortable: true
});
```

in the doc ready function.

i`m getting a JavaScript error on the page, saying "Property 'sortable': object is null or undefined". 
i can see in IE dev tools that the scripts are there.

tried to link all the individual scripts instead of the kendo.web.js bundle but just getting another error message : "kendo_module is undefined"

googled around, but no luck.

EDIT: saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867568/kendo-ui-grid-sortable-and-other-properties-not-working) question, but it`s not the case

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is about a simple sample with sorting I can come up with.  Does the sorting work for you on this ?  http://jsbin.com/asEFIju/1/edit

Comment: @giltnerj0 Thanks you for taking the time to write the sample. i see you are linking kendo.all.js, that i don't seem to have, i have kendo.web.js, is kendo.all .js also GPL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table has the expected format works fine.

Try the following HTML:

```
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Fred</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ted</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ed</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    sortable: true
});
```

Or click here : http://jsbin.com/AmECatE/1/edit (tested with IE 9)

Comment: hi, OnaBai same as have i commented above. i see you are linking kendo.all.js, that i don't seem to have, i have kendo.web.js, is kendo.all .js also GPL ?

Comment: I've used kendo.all.min.js but you don't need it, you can do the same with `kendo.web.min.js`. See it here: http://jsbin.com/AmECatE/2/edit. No, I don't think that kendo.all.min.js is GPL since it includes inside some KendoUI packages that are not. BTW: try not including scripts that you don't need as in this example: mobile, dataviz,... that makes your much slower to load and add more dependencies.

Comment: thanks, it`s so strange that my very similar case does not work on my workstation. i have to conclude it`s something wrong in my setup. i will try a clean start , and if this does not work i`ll accept this answer anyway.

Comment: Try removing any `script` that you don't need. Leave just the four that I included in the link.